# Resources in .NET satellite assembly not used

Tags: c#, .net, dll, localization

I am trying to create a batch script to produce localised versions of resource files. Following the various MSDN articles I compile the resources using resgen

resgen.exe "My.Resources\resources.ja-JP.resx" "My.Resources\obj\resources.ja-JP.resources"

I then use Al to create the dll

al.exe"  /culture:ja-JP /keyfile:"ResourceKey.snk" /out:"bin\ja-JP\My.Resources.resources.dll" /platform:x64 /template:"bin\My.Resources.resources.dll" /embed:"My.Operator.Resources\obj\resources.ja-JP.resources"

All of this works without error and produces a signed dll. However, when I use a test program to test it (again taken from an MSDN article) it does not find the localised resource but displays the generic language fallback instead. (if I swap the localised dll for one produced in Visual Studio all works fine)

Looking at the output in visual studio, it loads the dll withno errors.

Looking at the ResourceManager object in the debugger it appears to have loaded the fallback resources twice (but this is probably irrelevant)

The Fusion log is silent on the matter (i.e. no errors relating to the resource dlls.

Does anybody have any suggestions about what I am doing wrong? Is there any way of persuading .Net to provide further information about why it is ignoring the localised dll?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting the current culture in your test program?

Comment: I am settingthe CurrentThred CurrentCulture and CurrentUiCulture.

Comment: I should note that if I use a satellite assembly produced by VisualStudio I see the translated resources. I am unable to spot a major difference between the commands VisualStudio uses (for resgenand al0 and the ones used in my script.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the /template switch to al.exe should specify the executable file of the application.

It looks like you have specified the neutral resource file.

If that is not the error, I suggest that you build your project from the command line with msbuild, and examine the exact command lines which it uses.